# beyondcode/laravel-websockets package not install on laravel 10.8 Framework

Tags: laravel-websockets, laravel-10

**beyondcode/laravel-websockets** package in the Laravel **10.8** Framework then it causes an error in the command prompt like this

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

I have set the required settings in composer.json

```json
"require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.14",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.8",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
    }
```

Answer (score 20):

I think you are facing the version problem with beyondCode laravel websocket package I had same problem after searching I found this youtube video that explains how to install beyondcode laravel web socket on laravel 10.

```
composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets -w
```

https://youtu.be/8RL584c7EsI

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from incompatible php version,

> beyondcode/laravel-websockets

beyond code is incompatible with your PHP version (8.1).

write hyphen w at the end of command

> -w

`-w` is the short form of **`--with-all-dependencies`** say to composer install the package and its all dependencies.

[Laravel WebSockets Doc](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction)